# When should I capitalize the word "principal"?

Tags: capitalization

When using the word *Principal* to describe the head or director of a school, under what situations should one capitalize it, and when should it be lower-cased?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Principal* should be capitalized when used as a title preceding the name of the person but uncapitalized if used as a description following the name. For example,

> Let us welcome Principal Bob.
>
> Let us welcome Bob, the principal of the school.

See for example *[Blue Book of Grammar and Punctuation](http://grammarbook.com/punctuation/capital.asp)*.

Comment: What about in the case of something like "The Pittsburgh High School Pricipal's Office" vs "The Pittsburgh High School principal's office"?

Comment: It would be "the Pittsburgh High School Principal's office" (used as a title) or "the Pittsburgh High School's principal's office" (descriptive common noun belonging to the school).

Answer (score 2):

Tips on the capitalization of the word *principal*:

- you should capitalize the word *principal* when it goes before a proper noun, such as "Principal Skinner", or "Mr. Skinner, Principal of Springfield Elementary School".
- you should not capitalize the word *principal* when the word stands alone without a person's name like "we're sending you to the principal".